# How to use UseLoggerFactory in conjunction with UseInternalServiceProvider

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

We have an asp.net core Web API and registering our EF DB context like so

```
services
            .AddDbContext<SiteDbContext>((serviceProvider, opt) =>
            {
                opt
                    .UseNpgsql(options.Site)
                    .UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider)
                    ;
            })
```

The DB Context calls DbContextOptionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory which fails.
Looking at this doco https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder.useloggerfactory?view=efcore-5.0
It is mentioned that you can't do what I just did above and suggested to *"In this case, the ILoggerFactory should be configured directly in that service provider."*

My question is how is that specifically done? to configure directly in that service provider.

Comment: Why are you trying to replace the internal service provider? EF Core uses it for its own internal services

Answer (score 3):

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder.useinternalserviceprovider?view=efcore-5.0) (emphasis mine):

> Sets the `IServiceProvider` that the context should resolve all of its services from. EF will create and manage a service provider if none is specified.
>
> The service provider **must contain all the services required by Entity Framework (and the database being used)**. The Entity Framework services can be registered using an extension method on `IServiceCollection`. For example, the Microsoft SQL Server provider includes an `AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()` method to add the required services.

You shouldn't try to replace the internal service provider with the app-level service provider unless you register every single internal service EF core needs.

If you actually need to set the logger factory, there's an easier way to configure it. Use an overload that gives you an `IServiceProvider`:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>((provider, options) =>
{
    var loggerFactory = provider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
    options
        .UseNpgsql(/* ... */)
        .UseLoggerFactory(loggerFactory);
});
```