# What is the correct way to use computed properties with Dynamic LINQ?

Tags: c#, dynamic-linq, ef-core-6.0

I have these models.

```
public class Ticket
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public List<History> History {get;set;}
}

public class History
{
    public Employee Employee {get;set;}
    public string Comments {get;set;}
    public DateTime Timestamp {get;set;}
}
```

`Employee` is just a class with an `int Id` and `string Name`.

What I had in mind is that I needed to allow the users to query `Tickets` by a computed property in `Tickets`, such as

```
public Employee LatestEmployee
{
    get => History.MaxBy(x=>x.Timestamp).Employee;
}
```

From the user, I get the name of the queried property/column, the search term and whether the user wants it to *contain*, *start with* or *be equal to*, and I'm using dynamic LINQ, so I can concatenate multiple queries as the user applies further filters. Basically I get a JSON like this:

```
{
    "column":"Employee",
    "query":"Batman",
    "type":"equals"
}
```

Which is converted to a Dynamic LINQ `"Employee == Batman"`.

But on the database itself, it *still* creates an EmployeeId column with a foreign key, so I need to fill it with a random (existing, because of the FK) value.

I, then, query it as

```
var filteredListQuery = 
_context.Tickets.Include(x=>x.History)
    .ThenInclude(y=>y.Employee)
.Where("Employee.Name == \"Batman\"");
```

Following that, I must return a JSON with information on the tickets to display. So I try

```
var filteredListQueryDTO = filteredListQuery
.Select(x=>new TicketDTO()
{
    Id = x.Id.ToString(),
    Employee = x.Employee.Name,
    Timestamp = x.Timestamp.ToString("g")
}).ToListAsync();
```

But then it reads the employee saved on the unnecesary column, rather than using the computed property. And if I try `Employee = x.History.MaxBy(x=>x.Timestamp).Employee.Name` I get a `LINQ expression could not be translated`.

It does work, though, if I, as per the linked KB article on the exception, first call `ToList()` on the `filteredQueryList()`:

```
var filteredListQueryDTO = (await filteredListQuery.ToListAsync())
.Select(x=>new TicketDTO()
{
    Id = x.Id.ToString(),
    Employee = x.Employee.Name,
    Timestamp = x.Timestamp.ToString("g")
}).ToList();
```

Or if I iterate through filteredListQuery with a foreach loop (which I think is pretty much the same).

Is there an easier (less convoluted and more professional) way to do this (and without the extra unused column on the database)?

Comment: Why do you want to use dynamic LINQ? what is the package that you are using?

Comment: I need the query to be constructed at runtime, as I can't know how the user will filter their query beforehand. The user might want to get only Tickets with Employee starting with "Bat", or Tickets opened between yesterday and now... So, the user-selected filters are transformed into a dynamic LINQ query string as the user changes their filters. The query will, then, populate a table with the information.

Comment: I ?think? you need to learn how to build an IQueryable with "optional" parameters.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it best to make my actual Entity models reflect the database structure as closely as possible, and largely use them for CRUD operations. You can create a separate class to represent other queryable facets of your entity, but instead of using computed properties, use mapping logic to create a projection for those properties.

```
public class TicketSummary
{
    public int TicketId {get;set;}
    public Employee LatestEmployee {get;set;}
}
```

```
public IQueryable<TicketSummary> BuildSummaryQuery()
{
    return _context.Tickets.Select(t => new TicketSummary
        {
            TicketId = t.Id,
            LatestEmployee = t.History.MaxBy(x=>x.Timestamp).Employee
        });
}
```

Then you can apply your query criteria as appropriate. Using your dynamic LINQ example above, for example:

```
var filteredListQuery = BuildSummaryQuery()
    .Where("LatestEmployee.Name == \"Batman\"");
```

Comment: I've tried your example with a minimum reproductible example (the Dynamic LINQ query in your example should be `.Where("LatestEmployee.Name == \"Batman\"");`) and got a `The LINQ expression could not be translated`

Comment: That's unfortunate. If you just use `.Where(t => t.LatestEmployee.Name == "Batman")` does that work? I'm trying to figure out if the problem is with the `MaxBy` method or with the dynamic LINQ library.

Comment: Same error. Some further info: Instantiating the query itself does not raise the exception. Instead, calling `filteredListQuery.ToList()` is what raises it.

Comment: That's unsurprising: creating the query is a very light-weight operation: the work is done upon evaluation of the query. It looks like EF Core doesn't support MaxBy yet. What happens if you replace `MaxBy(...)` with `.OrderByDescending(...).FirstOrDefault()` (or `First` if you can guarantee at least one History per ticket)?

Comment: That did the trick. I changed `TicketSummary` to have a `TicketId` property and a `LatestHistory` property. So the query is separated in four stages. Get the `Tickets` and `Include` `Histories`; Then `Select` new `TicketSummary`, in which `TicketId` comes from the selected `Ticket` and `LatestHistory` comes from the selected `Ticket`'s `Histories.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Timestamp).FirstOrDefault()`. Then I can apply any other filters I want (even using Dynamic LINQ). Thanks for the assist!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. By the way, there is no need to include histories. Include only impacts things when you're loading the original Entity type out. Since you're creating a projection (e.g. TicketDTO or TicketSummary), it has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, instead of "dynamic", you will use a parameters object, and *optionally* "if" the parameters are populated, you will add in optional parts of your `IQueryable`.

```
public class OrganizationSearchArgs
{
    public string OrganizationNameNotLike { get; set; } = null;

    public ICollection<int> OrgStatuses { get; set; } = new List<int>();

    public ICollection<string> OrganizationNamesIn { get; set; } = new List<string>();

    public ICollection<string> OrganizationNamesNotIn { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

(below would be a class that exposes functionality on your dbcontext)

```
    public async Task<int> GetListByArgsCount(OrganizationSearchArgs args, CancellationToken token)
    {
        IQueryable<OrganizationEntity> qry = this.GetGetListByArgsBaseIQueryable(args);
        int returnValue = await qry.CountAsync(token);
        return returnValue;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<OrganizationEntity>> GetListByArgs(
        OrganizationSearchArgs args,
        CancellationToken token)
    {
        IQueryable<OrganizationEntity> qry = this.GetGetListByArgsBaseIQueryable(args);

        List<OrganizationEntity> entities = await qry.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync(token);


        return entities;
    }

    private IQueryable<OrganizationEntity> GetGetListByArgsBaseIQueryable(OrganizationSearchArgs args)
    {
        IQueryable<OrganizationEntity> qry = this.entityDbContext.Organizations
            .Include(org => org.SomeNavigationProperty).AsNoTracking();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.OrganizationNameNotLike))
        {
            qry = qry.Where(o => !o.OrganizationName.Contains(args.OrganizationNameNotLike));
        }


        if (null != args.OrgStatuses && args.OrgStatuses.Any())
        {
            qry = qry.Where(org => args.OrgStatuses.Contains(org.OrgStatus));
        }

        if (null != args.OrganizationNamesIn && args.OrganizationNamesIn.Any())
        {
            qry = qry.Where(org => args.OrganizationNamesIn.Contains(org.OrganizationName));
        }

        if (null != args.OrganizationNamesNotIn && args.OrganizationNamesNotIn.Any())
        {
            qry = qry.Where(org => !args.OrganizationNamesNotIn.Contains(org.OrganizationName));
        }

        return qry;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is now corrected.

Comment: I wanted to edit, rather than delete my previous comment, I'm sorry. Also, suppose I have more properties to filter from. Would I need to add a group of those arguments for each property?

Comment: I'm showing you the "idea".  You have some kind of MySearchArgs and you add as few/many things as you want.  Then you tweak ("build up") the IQueryable based on that object, or rather if it has things populated or not.   Its the idea that is important, not the exact syntax sugar.  you're making your data layer "flexible", (not "dynamic" in the sense you are using the word dynamic).  You have strong typed objects.....but you have optional where clauses.

Comment: I understood. My actual model can, currently, be filtered by 10 properties. Some are numeric/dateTime (so I'd use "between" or "equals"), some are strings ("containing", "startingWith", "equals"). So, for each property, I would need a set of searchArguments, right? Is it ok, then, if my parameters object have almost 30 parameters?

Comment: Then "yes".  You have to code up any/all "Placeholders" on the Args object.  And then add the accompanying IQueryable-altering code.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion with a minimum reproductible example, and I got the same error as StriplingWarrior's suggestion. I believe the issue is with the query itself - I think MaxBy must have some kind of restriction that can't be successfully translated to MySQL

Comment: Then suggest figuring out how to wire up seeing the generated SQL.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder.useloggerfactory?view=efcore-6.0 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68811701/how-to-use-useloggerfactory-in-conjunction-with-useinternalserviceprovider

Answer (score 0):

**Without Dynamic LINQ Library:**

```
 public static class ExpressionBuilder
 {
 public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildPredicate<T>(string propertyName, string comparison, object value)
    {
        if (propertyName == null) return t => true;
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var left = propertyName.Split('.').Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Expression.PropertyOrField);
        var body = MakeComparison(left, comparison, value);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
    }

    static Expression MakeComparison(Expression left, string comparison, object value)
    {
        var constant = Expression.Constant(value, left.Type);
        switch (comparison)
        {
            case "==":
                return Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, left, constant);
            case "!=":
                return Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.NotEqual, left, constant);
            case ">":
                return Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.GreaterThan, left, constant);
            case ">=":
                return Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual, left, constant);
            case "<":
                return Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.LessThan, left, constant);
            case "<=":
                return Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual, left, constant);
            case "Contains":
            case "StartsWith":
            case "EndsWith":
                if (value is string)
                {
                    return Expression.Call(left, comparison, Type.EmptyTypes, constant);
                }
                throw new NotSupportedException($"Comparison operator '{comparison}' only supported on string.");
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException($"Invalid comparison operator '{comparison}'.");
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var data = querable.Where(ExpressionBuilder.BuildPredicate("Name", "==", "Batman"));
```