# Inability to use "MaxBy" on "Where" clauses with EFCore + MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, dynamic-linq, ef-core-6.0

My database has the following structure:

```
public class Ticket
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<History> Histories { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class History
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

The user provides the name of the property to filter by and the query string. What I had in mind is that I needed to allow the users to query `Tickets` by a computed property in `Tickets`, such as

```
public Employee LatestEmployee
{
    get => History.MaxBy(x=>x.Timestamp).Employee;
}
```

I was suggested to leave the Entity models strictly to reflect the db structure and use a separate class to represent queryable properties of the entity:

```
public class TicketSummary
{
    public int TicketId {get;set;}
    public Employee LatestEmployee {get;set;}
}

public IQueryable<TicketSummary> BuildSummaryQuery()
{
    return _context.Tickets.Select(t => new TicketSummary
        {
            TicketId = t.Id,
            LatestEmployee = t.History.MaxBy(x=>x.Timestamp).Employee
        });
}
```

And then call `BuildSummaryQuery().Where(x=>x.LatestEmployee.Name == "Batman")`. However, I found out `MaxBy()` could not be translated into a valid query on the MySQL Database. I keep getting a `The LINQ expression could not be translated`. How can I work out a similar, valid query?

Comment: `MaxBy` is quite new, and providers need to be modified to understand it in order to generate the correct SQL query. The EF Core provider for MySQL just needs to be updated to support it.  The MySqlConnector one will probably get it before Oracle's does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per StriplingWarrior's comment ([What is the correct way to use computed properties with Dynamic LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72943166/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-computed-properties-with-dynamic-linq/72943755?noredirect=1#comment128860476_72944625)), instead of using `MaxBy()`, I successfully managed to create a valid query using `OrderByDescending()` and `FirstOrDefault()`

First, instead of computed properties on the entity, the actual queryable entity is

```
public class TicketSummary
{
    public string TicketId { get; set; }
    public History? LatestHistory { get; set; }
}
```

Then, the query is composed as follows

```
//Includes the tables needed for the filterable properties.
var firstQuery = _context.Tickets.Include(t => t.Histories).ThenInclude(h => h.Employee);

//Creates an IQueryable<TicketSummary> with the latest History entity
var ticketSummariesQueryable = firstQuery.Select(x => new TicketSummary
{
    TicketId = x.Id.ToString(),
    LatestHistory = x.Histories.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Timestamp).FirstOrDefault()
});

//Finally apply the filters given by the user
var filteredQuery = ticketSummariesQueryable.Where(ts=>ts.LatestHistory.Employee.Name == "Black Canary");
```

This way the most recent `History` is stored on `LatestHistory` to be promptly used on queries.